# Specifying custom nested objects in Django Rest Framework ModelSerializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have lat, long specified in my DB as:

```
...
lat = models.DecimalField(_('Latitude'), max_digits=8, decimal_places=5, null=True, blank=True)
lng = models.DecimalField(_('Longitude'), max_digits=8, decimal_places=5, null=True, blank=True)
...
```

I want my ModalSerialization to come out as:

```
{
  ...
  "location": {
      "lat": ...,
      "long": ... 
  }
  ...
}
```

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the way is you can create a property in a model like below.

```
@property
def location_info(self):
    return dict(
        lat=self.lat,
        lng=self.lng
    )
```

Then you can create a dict field in your serializer and specify source as your property. Since it is property it can be readonly field.

```
location = serializers.DictField(source='location_info', read_only=True)
```